# Получить строку из БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Привет всем.

Есть БД, из нее мне нужно получить строку, которая находится в таблице Avto, имя базы AvtoBazar. Управляется база SQL Server CE. Подключение к базе через

```
SqlCeConnection sqlCE = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\DB\AvtoBazar.sdf;");
```

проходит успешно. Но вот есть стринговая переменная в коде, которой нужно присвоить из таблицы Avto из поля NameAvto конкретное значение. Ну или хотя бы получить коллекцию значений со строками из NameAvto. Однако ума не хватает понять, как это сделать. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, на самом простом примере. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо открыть соединение

```
SqlCeConnection.Open();
```

После этого создайте объект команды передав в него SQL запрос и объект соединения. Выполните запрос и получите данные в виде объекта SqlCeDataReader. В цикле из дата ридера вы сможете достать необходимые значения.

```
string sqlQueryString = "Select NameAvto From Avto"; //для конкретного значения добавь Where
SqlCeCommand comand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlQueryString, sqlCE);
SqlCeDataReader dataReader = comand.executeReader();

List<string> avtoNames = new List<string>();
while(dataReader.Read()){
  avtoNames.add(dataReader.getString(0));
}
dataReader.close();
```

Comment: О, спасибо. Помогло. Теперь буду разбираться в деталях по этому коду